# Rails: MassAssignmentSecurity::Error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, exception, mass-assignment

Following [the ruby on rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#countermeasures) developer can't mass-assign protected fields but don't get exception trying to do it, right?
But in my case mass-assignment different params through `new` method in `rails` application:

```
@edition = Edition.new params[:edition]
```

raise following exception:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: price
```

Why? Did I understand something incorrectly? Is it a way not to get the mass-assignment exception? It's not convenient to delete protected attributes from hashes before assignments i think.

**Update:** Edition model:

```
class Edition < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :description
  attr_protected :price
end
```

`params[:edition].inspect`:

```
{"title"=>"t", "description"=>"d", "price"=>"123"}
```

Comment: Do you have `attr_accessible` in your model?

Comment: Yes, have `attr_accessible` fields and only one `attr_protected` `price` field.

Comment: Try removing it from attr_protected. If it's not in attr_accessible, it still won't be mass-assigned, but you shouldn't get exceptions anymore.

Comment: Still get the exception even after commenting attr_protected line. Only attr_accessible fields were left.

Comment: Could you add `params[:edition].inspect` and your attr_accessible fields to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to assign protected attribute price in mass assignment by putting

```
@edition = Edition.new params[:edition]
```

That is a mass assignment of variables and in params[:edition] according to your edit, there is the variable price which according to your code cannot be mass assigned.

To fix this you either have to remove the protection on price which I do not think you would want to do or mass-assign only the unprotected variables with new and then assign the protected variable.  SO:

```
    @edition = Edition.new params[:edition].except("price")
    @edition.price = params[:edition]['price']
```

OR `@edition = Edition.new params[:edition], :without_protection => true`

EDIT: news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3780963 Rails 3.23 now makes the validation strict by default which raises that exception. The documentation is out of date.

Comment: ok, but what about examples in ruby on rails guide? You can find the link at the top of the question. They don't do any removing.

Comment: Yeah they pass :without_protection with it.  The crux of the problem is still the same.  You are trying to mass assign a protected variable.  You can also bypass the check with :without_protection.  The purpose of mass-assignment protection is to avoid someone doing User.update(params) on a REST call and have an attacker pass in :admin=>true when the intent was just to update their password.

Comment: I think the main thing here is that you need to understand the security risks of mass-assignment and know why you are having this problem.

Comment: thanks for your help. Please, look at the code example after words 'If you want to set a protected attribute, you will to have to assign it individually'. They don't have any exceptions, do they? Why?

Comment: they have the without_protection flag to bypass it, but you really shouldn't do that.  But understand that this protection exists because the creator of the model has decided that this field has a potential security threat if it is set with every other variable all at once.  That is why they make it explicit to be set.  Read about mass-assignment vulnerabilities and you will see what they are doing here and why they are making it difficult.

Comment: you say "It's not convenient to delete protected attributes from hashes before assignments i think."  You are 100% right and that is what they are trying to do.  They do not want you to inadvertently set a protected variable through mass-assignment.  If you have no need to protect something, remove protection.

Comment: Sorry, but i really can't see any flag in the code example after the words. Here is the code exactly after them: http://pastebin.com/aBjksWYY . Looks like no exception. ps: it's clear    that there is no need to protect price field. It' just an example.

Comment: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3780963  Rails 3.23 now makes the validation strict by default which raises that exception.  The documentation is out of date.

Comment: Oh, Thanks for help. Please, add it to the answer.

Comment: For future Googlers, the params part should be 'params[:edition].except("price")'. Delete returns the value for the deleted key instead of the new hash. The rails function 'except' does just that.