# Error while trying to implement edit in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to edit a view called categories in my project,but I seems to get a very strange error while trying to do so.

The error which is shown is as follows:-

```
    ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in CategoriesController#update

    Can't mass-assign protected attributes: id, name, parent_cat_id

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"RaQQRvJRRmjg0HAy3utlrD2wKAvYXbtNC2hjR4JHpXs=",
 "category"=>{"id"=>"3",
 "name"=>"Non-Fictional",
 "parent_cat_id"=>"0"},
 "commit"=>"Update",
 "id"=>"3"}
```

My category table is as follows:-

```
id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255),
  parent_cat_id integer DEFAULT 0,
  deleted integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT categories_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

My category model file is as follows:-

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :name, :parent_cat_id

    # ------- ASSOCIATIONS -----------

    has_many :books

    belongs_to :category, :foreign_key => 'parent_cat_id'
end
```

Can anyone please help me with this

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014049/rails-massassignmentsecurityerror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add fields(id, name, parent_cat_id) to `Category model` which should be mass-assigned -

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :parent_cat_id, :id
    # ------- ASSOCIATIONS -----------
  has_many :books
  belongs_to :category, :foreign_key => 'parent_cat_id'
end
```

Comment: Show your `CategoriesController#update` method implementation?